# Add child using Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How do I add a child after `.onWrite` using Cloud Functions?

[image]

Code skeleton:

```
exports.addNewValue = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
// add child newValue: "randomValue" to the newly added key above
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the database at the same location where the change occurred with some key/value pair:

```
event.data.adminRef.update({key:"value"})
```

I suggest also getting acquainted with the documentation for how to work with [database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), and [how to write to Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) using the JavaScript API.

Comment: I have a problem. If the value is `Date.now()`, the function get stuck in an infinite loop. How to fix this?

Comment: try with `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`(don't forget to import admin : `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';`)